# How do I call FutureBuilder again when snapshot.data is null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to restart the future after showing the `CircularProgressIndicator`. How do I accomplish this?

When my phone has no data/wifi, the snapshot state `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done` **is true**, so the `snapshot.data` is null.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<ADBeanData>>(
        future: makeGETRequest("http:www.mywebfite.com/load.php?hi=true"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              this.this_went_offline = true;
              //timer_refresh_messages = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => RestartWidget.restartApp(context));//I want to do something like this
              //I want to restart the future after showing the CircularProgressIndicator
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // loading 
            }
              return PageView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
             //do stuff
             //The rest of my code contains the normal checks for connection state: 
            }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Text("loading ...");
           }else{
```

### Future:

```
 Future<List<ADBeanData>> makeGETRequest(String url) async {
    ADBeanData ad_bean_data = new ADBeanData();
    Response response = await get(url);
    var json_data = json.decode(response.body);
    List<ADBeanData> ad_bean_list = [];
    for (var u in json_data) {
      ADBeanData ad_bean = ADBeanData.set(
          u["ad_id"],
          u["user_id"],
          u["category"]
      );
      ad_bean_list.add(ad_bean);
    }
    print(ad_bean_list.length);
    return ad_bean_list;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of the `Future` `makeGETRequest`?

Comment: Sure, I added it right now

Answer (score 0):

Just call `setState` to "restart" the `Future`.

Example with your code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<ADBeanData>>(
        future: makeGETRequest("http:www.mywebfite.com/load.php?hi=true"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              this.this_went_offline = true;
              if(!timer_refresh_messages?.isActive()) {
                timer_refresh_messages = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => setState((){}));
              }
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // loading 
            }
              timer_refresh_messages?.cancel();
              return PageView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
             //do stuff
             //The rest of my code contains the normal checks for connection state: 
            }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Text("loading ...");
           }else{
```

As `makeGETRequest()` is within the `FutureBuilder`, reloading this segment via `setState` will also reload data.

Comment: This worked, but the timer is still running and making copy's of itself over and over

Comment: @Petro Oh yeah that's not good. Could you be more specific about the behavior?

Comment: Even if i do this, it still runs the timer over and over each time it's rebuilding, making more background timers `timer_refresh_messages = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => setState((){timer_refresh_messages.cancel();}));`

Comment: @Petro You have to cancel the timer when you get real data.

Comment: Ahh so run the cancel in the `not null` `snapshot.data` situation then? I'll try that

Comment: @Petro I edited my response to include my recommended cancelling code.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to be stopping all of the timers that ran while it was offline to stop

Comment: @Petro Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214697/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-petro).